# jwt authorization problem ASP.NET web api

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, jwt

I have a problem with issuing JWT token.

When I add `[Authorize]` to the API endpoint in my controller, and I try to access it via Swagger or Postman, it returns with an error 404.
(JWT is being send in headers).

[image: postman]

JWT:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJFbWFpbCI6IjIyMjJAR01BSUwuQ09NIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZWlkZW50aWZpZXIiOiI4NzY2OTY1ZS0wMDU1LTQ1NWMtYWFjOS1mZmI3MDdiOGExZjkiLCJVc2VySWQiOiI4NzY2OTY1ZS0wMDU1LTQ1NWMtYWFjOS1mZmI3MDdiOGExZjkiLCJleHAiOjE2OTk5NjQzNTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZ3Jvb3Zlc3luYy5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZ3Jvb3Zlc3luYy5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldCJ9.zJxkLPBAH4TO7Vvl6NH1MtKEGK2axvuhqtYtzqm0V5A

The Web API is being hosted in Azure for students.

`Startup.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["AuthSettings:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"));
    options.AddPolicy("Artist", policy => policy.RequireRole("artist"));
    options.AddPolicy("Studio", policy => policy.RequireRole("studio"));
    options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireRole("user"));
});
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
"AuthSettings": {
    "Key": "x",
    "Audience": "https://groovesync.azurewebsites.net",
    "Issuer": "https://groovesync.azurewebsites.net" 
},
```

Comment: What credentials was used in the client when the token was requested?  When you use [Authorize] the client credentials are used to access the route.  Error 404 indicates the token is failing the [Authorize] because the wrong credentials (or the credentials aren't authorized) for the route.

Comment: Your JWT looks legit. The 404 Not Found error is likely unrelated to the JWT. It should be a 401 or 403 to indicate an authentication issue.

Comment: Is it safe to share Key value on SO?

Comment: @beautifulcoder endpoint without [Authorize], works perfectly fine is it possible that the endpoint would change after adding this?

Comment: @jdweng can u elaborate? I am totally new to this.

Comment: Add Bearer Token in your postman. AddJwtBearer expects header like "Authorization" : "Bearer <yourtoken here>"

Comment: Looks like you are using Groovy.  See following : https://github.com/denschu/job-dsl-examples/blob/master/job-dsl-authentication-example.groovy.  The example show the user credentials are being used.  The route on the server needs to allow the user access.  You are using Basic Authentication.  Server may be set to OAUTH2.  See following for more info : https://itecnote.com/tecnote/http-authentication-in-groovy

Comment: Looking at the jwt, it does not contains any role. are you requiring specific role to access the api ?

Comment: Usually, I will use [the Bearer Token this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ehTk.png), you can use it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me, is changing configuration of JWT authorization in **startup.cs**, adding Default Schemas resolved the issue of 404.

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["AuthSettings:Key"])),
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"));
    options.AddPolicy("Artist", policy => policy.RequireRole("artist"));
    options.AddPolicy("Studio", policy => policy.RequireRole("studio"));
    options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireRole("user"));
});
```